# JSP Error: Only a type can be imported. package.class resolves to a package

Tags: jsp, tomcat, error-handling

my project is develop website using JSP. In this project, the JSP file will call a function from my java file.

Here is how I import my java file:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*,de.fraport.mobileformular.CreateEngine,org.activiti.engine.*,org.activiti.engine.runtime.*"%>
```

Then, here is how I call my method:

```
<%
    //deploy process from activiti
    CreateEngine ce = new CreateEngine();
%>
```

But, I don't know why, when I load above page, it will generate following error:

[image: Error while Loading Page]

FYI: this web application running on Tomcat 7 and connected to Activiti Workflow Engine.

Thanks for your help.

Edited:

Here is the deployed class:

```
package de.fraport.mobileformular;

import org.activiti.engine.*;
import org.activiti.engine.runtime.*;

public class CreateEngine {

    //set global variable
    ProcessEngine processEngine;
    RepositoryService repositoryService;
    RuntimeService  runtimeService;
    ProcessInstance processInstance;

    //method for deploying and start process
    public void deployProcess()
    {
        processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();
        repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();

        repositoryService.createDeployment()
          .addClasspathResource("accidentForm.bpmn20.xml")
          .deploy();

        runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
        processInstance = runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("accidentForm");;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it can't find that type.

Comment: but, i've import the class file @dave

Comment: No, you've *attempted* to import the class, and it cannot be found. Is it deployed?

Comment: yes it is. How can solve it?

Comment: Deploy the missing class. Looks like what you believe is a class name is a package. Post the package and class declaration, not the code, for the class you've packaged incorrectly.

Comment: I have add the deployed class to my question. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: Where precisely is it deployed? Are you sure you're running the code you think you are? The error message is very clear, and it's highly unlikely it's incorrect, although it's possible.

Comment: it is deployed on my localhost above my tomcat 7. I think so. Is there a way about how to find out if I am running the right code (the one that I think)?

Comment: I mean where is the class in the war or directory hierarchy.

Comment: in directory hierarchy

Comment: WHERE IS THE CLASS IN THE DIRECTORY HIERARCHY.

Comment: it is on my bin folder

Comment: WHERE in your bin folder? Come on: the error states exactly what the issue is. We can't see over your shoulder to check your packaging and deployment. We rely on the information you give us to diagnose the problem. No information means no hope of diagnosis. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved by change the type of the project from Java Project into Dynamic Web Project. Thanks