# page import directives are duplicated

Tags: jsp, import, duplicates, resolve

I have two pages. A and B.

A and B have to import the same package Such as

In page A,

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Calendar" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.TimeZone" %>
```

And in page B,

```
<%@ page import="java.util.TimeZone" %>
```

============================================

Problem is..

I have to include page B within the page A sometimes

and if I do that, it makes duplication exception.

Right now, my server doesn't throw the duplication exception

but I got the exception from the other server which is not mine.

It look just like this [image](http://www.google.co.kr/imgres?imgurl=https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyJf0.png&imgrefurl=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761810/jsp-error-only-a-type-can-be-imported-package-class-resolves-to-a-package&h=836&w=1191&tbnid=8bL0R7i4MLOM_M:&zoom=1&docid=BBzUR-ERDPs8sM&ei=W0hHVc2JEeTRmAXxs4CwAw&tbm=isch&ved=0CBsQMygAMAA).

"Only a type can be imported blar blar".

============================================

Is there any way to make sure that the package is imported only one time??

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

The image is just an example. Point is this sentence; "Only a type can be imported blar blar".

Let me make things clear.

1. I made two pages. A and B.
2. Each pages imports class T with 'page import' directive of jsp.
3. Page B has a variable of class T.

   T inst = new T();
4. Page A includes page B with 'include' directive of jsp.
5. I access to the page A, I get this compile error sometimes

   Only a type can be imported. java.util.T resolves to a package.

I believe this is caused because I imported the same library in two different pages and I included page B in page A.

Is there any way to solve this without any server configuration??

Comment: I cannot understand the question. Title speaks of duplication of import directives, and the error occurs at line `CreateEngine ce = new CreateEngine()` saying that `CreateEngine`is a package ... Currently question is *unclear*.

Comment: @SergeBallesta The image is just an example. Point is this sentence "Only a type can be imported blar blar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common file that is shared by each page A and B. You can write your import statements in it and only include it at the top of the main page. Avoid imports from A and B. That way you can make sure imports will not be duplicated. I have used this approach in many projects. In situation like this I envy PHP's require_once / include_once

Hope this will help you.

Enjoy

Comment: Now I find out that it wasn't jsp code problem. There was duplicated libraries in server. That's why tomcat  couldn't determine which to work with.